# How do I get vim to input the bar/pipe character in my vimrc?

Tags: vim, vimrc

I've tried the following, but it doesn't work.

```
inoremap <C-\> <Esc>$a<Space>do<Space><Bar><Bar><CR>end<Esc>k$i
```

I'm trying to map a shortcut for ruby `do || .. end` blocks.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure your mapping does what you want it to do but, at least, the `||` insertion works, here.

Comment: It works for me. I get " do ||
end" (with a newline before "end") when I run the mapping, with the cursor between the pipe/bar characters in insert mode.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to insert some boilerplate code. There are several ways to approach this:

- Take a look at the [vim-snipmate](https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim) ViM plugin. Does what you want and then some. Highly recommended.
- Record a sequence of keypresses (`:help q`), which you can later replay (`:help @`). This sequence is recorded in the register, which is not the same as mapping/macro, but achieves your goal still, plus it can be made persistent (i.e. survive ViM restarts).
- Do an actual mapping: `:inoremap <C-\> <Esc>A<Space>do<Space><Bar><Bar><CR>end<Esc>ko`

Hope this helps.